# How to unzip a file on remove FTP without downloading it?

Tags: heroku, ftp, zip, remote-access

I need to manipulate hundreds of zip files ranging from 50Mb to 1500Mb.

Downloading them (particularly hard on heroku with their SquashFS transient system) doesn't seem viable.

Is there a way to remotely unzip files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no (at least not without SSH)

Extrapolating from Bobby's excellent answer here:(https://superuser.com/questions/479661/how-to-unzip-files-via-an-ftp-connection)
"It is not possible to unzip files remotely. FTP stands for "File Transfer Protocol", which was designed to transfer and partly manage files on the remote end, but not to execute commands. To unpack an archive you'd have to execute a program like tar, bzip2 or similar, but that's not possible via a FTP connection.

You need another session which allows you to execute commands, like SSH. Or you unpack the archive on your machine and transfer the contents via FTP, which will be considerable slower if you have a large number of small files because of the overhead of FTP."

Hope this helps.